# Does NUnit supports fluent syntax for C# dynamics?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dynamic, nunit, facebook-c#-sdk

I have an nUnit test case that asserts the dynamic that was returned from Facebook C# SDK. Is there any way how to assert it using NUnit fluent syntax. Here is very *simplified* example for what I'm looking for:

```cs
// not working
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic userInfo = client.Get("me");
Assert.That(userInfo, Is.Not.Null);
Assert.That(userInfo, Has.Property("id").Not.Null);
Assert.That(userInfo, Has.Property("name").Not.Null);
```

Right now I can only test by specifying 'properties' directly

```cs
// working, but not fluent
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic userInfo = client.Get("me");
Assert.That(userInfo, Is.Not.Null);
Assert.That(userInfo.id, Is.Not.Null);
Assert.That(userInfo.name, Is.Not.Null);
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

json  object is IDictionary<string.object> so you can use its methods.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic userInfo = client.Get("me");
var hasId = userInfo.ContainsKey("id");
```

I haven't used nunit fluent api but I'm guessing there might be some method like Has.Key()

Answer (score 2):

**prabir** gives me a good suggestion. At least I could check dynamic as *IDictionary* and use *[CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=collectionAssert&r=2.5.10)* for testing. It not 100% covers what I'm looking for, but it is most closest suggestion.

```
var client = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
dynamic userInfo = client.Get("me");
Assert.That(userInfo, Is.Not.Null);

var requiredDynamicProperties = new[] { "id", "name", "wtf" };

var dictionary = (userInfo as IDictionary<string, Object>);

CollectionAssert.IsSubsetOf(requiredDynamicProperties, dictionary.Keys); 
// message will describe in details that no "wtf" found
```

Answer (score 0):

So if userInfo is a IDynamicMetaObjectProvider, I believe NUnit `Has` will not work. Whether the NUnit constraint API could ever be modified to work depends on how it was implmemented. If it's implemented with reflection it is possible to use [dynamic invocation instead](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/dynamitey/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding). However, if it is implemented with expressions it won't ever work with real dynamic objects.

Comment: Now I have answer on [NUnit forum](https://answers.launchpad.net/nunit-3.0/+question/170909) — this feature not supported for now